# Why is doctype.com so much worse than the rest of the StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, doctype

Every other stack exchange site is awesome, but it seems that doctype.com doesn't use the same software. Quite frankly, the reason everyone still asks their markup questions on StackOverflow is because doctype.com can't compete. Does anyone know what's going on with this?

Comment: No offence, but who gave this an upvote? Doctype has friggin pre-rended screenshots of your code. 'sif that isn't awesome.

Comment: Do they not use votes? I didn't see them when browsing the questions.

Comment: @Farseeker - Cute screenshots of problem code are completely useless. How does that make doctype.com usable in any way?

Comment: completely useless? Do you live in an alternate universe, or have you never done technical support? A screenshot of a problem is worth a million words. Rather than saying "This code renders div 1 out of line with div 2, and div 3 is floating to the right..." so on and so forth for 500 words, you can post your code and get an instant screenshot which you can refer to. How is that useless??

Answer (score 12):

> Why is doctype.com so much worse than the rest of the StackExchange sites?

Because it's [not a StackExchange site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/)? :)

> Doctype was inspired by Stack Overflow, but it was custom-built and tailored to the needs of web designers by the fine folks at Litmus. [...]

Comment: In that case, why does StackExchange recommend doctype.com instead of Stack Overflow? Why not create a StackExchange site for front end questions?

Comment: @JeffAtwood doesn't consider HTML+CSS as "code" / doesn't consider it difficult enough; that SE sites are intended to be on a higher level

Comment: @Adam Nonsense. HTML and CSS questions are officially on-topic even on StackOverflow.com itself.

Comment: Guess I misinterpreted his comments on HTML+CSS questions on webmasters.SE as a comment on all SE sites when he must have meant **webmasters** have bigger problems (not that they don't code HTML & CSS)

Comment: @Adam yeah, he probably meant webmasters deals with higher-level stuff, would make sense.